# How to understand canonical ultrafilter in forcing chapter of Jech

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Am new to forcing (obviously...), and I got to read Definition 14.25 in Jech's Set Theory which defines the canonical ultrafilter $\dot{G}$ on the Boolean algebra $B$ which is:

$\dot{G}(\check{u})=u$ for every $u \in B$ and where $dom(\dot{G})=\{\check{u}: u \in B\}$

I understand that $\dot{G}$ is central in the boolean valued model approach to forcing since it somehow gives reason for the existence of a generic set. But I am a bit confused with the definition of $\dot{G}$ above and so I'd like to ask:

1. Is $\dot{G} \in V^B$ ?, where $V^B$ is the Boolean Valued model of Jech. If so, then how is it an ultrafilter on $B$?
2. How to prove that $\Vert \dot{G} \text{ is an ultrafilter on } B \Vert=1$

Am really grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\dot G\in V^B$: it is defined as a function $V^B\to B,$ and that's what it means to be an element of $V^B.$

It is not an ultrafilter on $B,$ it is a *name* for one. The precise statement of this is just your second question: $\Vert \mbox{$\dot G$ is an ultrafilter on $\check B$ }\Vert =1.$

To show this, we need to check that all the properties of an ultrafilter are true in $V^B.$

For instance, $$ \Vert \dot G\subseteq \check B\Vert = \prod_{u\in B} u \Rightarrow 1 = 1,$$ $$ \Vert \check 1\in \dot G\Vert = \sum_{u\in B}\Vert \check u= \check 1\Vert \cdot u = 1$$ (since $\Vert \check u = \check 1\Vert = 1$ for $u=1$), and for $u,v\in B,$ $$ \Vert \check u\in \dot G\Vert \cdot \Vert \check v\in \dot G\Vert = \sum_{u',v'
\in B}\Vert \check u'= \check u\Vert\cdot \Vert \check v'=\check v\Vert\cdot u\cdot v = u\cdot v = \dot G((u\cdot v)\check\;)=\Vert(u\cdot v)\check\;\in \dot G\Vert.$$

There are two other properties to check that I'll leave to you. Also, the one I did is a bit unfinished... why was it ok to assume the two elements were check names in $\check B$? (It has to do with the first thing I showed). More generally, how can we track it all the way back to $$ \Vert \forall x,y\in \dot G,\; x\cdot y\in \dot G\Vert=1$$ and what does $x\cdot y$ mean here exactly? ("$\cdot $" is not part of the forcing language).

I'm not sure I'd say $\dot G$ is central to the Boolean-valued model approach, but it is useful for linking it up with the "standard" approach.

Comment: okay thank you ! you saved my life, in Exercise 14.14 of Jech and in Definition 14.25, $\check{B}$ was written as $B$ which got me confused

Comment: @LinkL Ok, if this suffices I'll delete my comment below the question. Yes, often when there's a ground model object and there's not much risk of ambiguity, people omit the check.

Comment: by being central to the Boolean Valued model, I take it to mean that since $\dot{G}$ always exists in $V^B$ (using an appropriate mapping from the forcing conditions to $V^B$), we can use $\dot{G}$ to approximate the generic set $G$ in the "standard" approach, and somehow justify $G$ semantically ... but is this understanding correct ?

Comment: @LinkL Yeah, that's on the right track. It's really the same thing as the name for the generic (in the standard approach). Similarly to BVM's, you could (if you wanted to) do away with models altogether in the standard approach and only talk about the forcing relation... but you'll still want to make similar arguments, and so the name is useful for that.